# Xcode 10.1: Profile is not an "iOS In House" profile

Tags: ios, xcode, developer-program

I am attempting to distribute via the Enteprise method on my Xcode 10.1 so I can get the `.ipa` to the organization.

For App Thinning I selected All compatible device variants and selected Rebuild from Bitcode.

On the PROD.app select, I select the PROD mobile provisioning profile the organization provided to me, but I get the following error below:

[image]

What does this mean and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create your provisioning profile and certificate in "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" on Apple's Developer web site - you have chosen the wrong type of provisioning profile. You'll need to choose "In House" from under the "Distribution" headline in order to get the right kind of profile.

Comment: In my Case,I had selected Adhoc while generating my provision instead of the App Distribution option