# Provisioning profile is not an "iOS In House" profile

Tags: iphone, xcode, developer-program, ios

I am building `.ipa` my application for distribution. And here is he error I have got:

```
Encountered error while creating the IPA:
error: exportArchive: Provisioning profile "xxx.xxx.xxx" is not an "iOS In House" profile.
```

[Here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370110/xcode-10-1-profile-is-not-an-ios-in-house-profile), looks like I have found the solution of my problem, but, in list of profile creating options I just don't have this `iOS In House`.

[image]

So, then I have found out, that this is because I didn't enroll Apple Developer Enterprise Program (but I have paid for apple developer account).

**PS**. Here is certificate and profile I have now:

1. Certificate Type - iOS Distribution
2. Provisioning Profile - App Store

So, is there a way to change this profile?

Answer (score 1):

I was unintentionally building the app for ad-hoc signing and not App Store signing.

This application compiles: `flutter build ipa --export-options-plist=`pwd`/ExportOptions.plist`

The settings are from a file with option strings:

```
<key>method</key>
<string>enterprise</string>
```

Changing `enterprise` to `app-store` allows code signing to avoid needing an enterprise certificate.